# Custom Theme not being implemented to DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an extension of `DialogFragment` here:

```
class AlertDialogFragment(context: Context) : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity).apply {
            setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
            setNeutralButton("Cancel", object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {

                }
            })
            setPositiveButton("Replace", object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {

                }
            })
            setNegativeButton("Delete", object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {

                }
            })
        }
        return dialog.create()
    }

}
```

As you can see above I have applied my `AlertDialogTheme` to the dialog:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

However when my dialog is shown:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    if (v is AppCompatImageButton){
        val dialog = AlertDialogFragment(this)
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "alertDialog")
    }
}
```

The background of the dialog is black (~#333 I think). My `@color/colorPrimary` is white so that is what the background is meant to be.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` takes a theme as a parameter. Is there a reason you're not using that and instead calling `setStyle`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
class AlertDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false)

        view.delete.setOnClickListener {  }

        view.cancel.setOnClickListener {  }

        view.replace.setOnClickListener {  }

        return view
   }    

}
```

create xml layout **fragment_dialog** and design it as you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

     <Button
           android:id="@+id/cancel"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="cancel"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
           android:id="@+id/replace"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="replace"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
           android:id="@+id/delete"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="delete"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

and finally show your dialog with your custom style just like that :

```
val dialog = AlertDialogFragment()
dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME , R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "alertDialog")
```